# Adding an np.array as a column in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and a numpy nd array with one dimension. Effectively it is a list.

How do I add a new column to the DataFrame with the values from the array?

`test['preds'] = preds` gives `SettingWithCopyWarning`
And a warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

And when I try `pd.DataFrame({test,preds})` I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: What is your original df? if `test` is already a df then `test['preds']=preds` would work.

Comment: To answer the `SettingWithCopyWarning` you need to post your original DataFrame

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to EdChum the problem was this

```
test= DataFrame(test)
test['preds']=preds
```

It works!

Comment: I get this warning: `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pandas error, this error is because you are trying to instantiate a set with two lists.

```
{test,preds}
#TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

A set is a container which needs all its content to be hashable, since sets may not contain the same element twice.

That being said, handing pandas a set will not work for your desired result.

Handing pandas a dict however, will work, like this:

```
pd.DataFrame({"test":test,"preds":preds})
```